# How to make all collapsible webparts to be open at once after clicking on image button

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have more collapsible webparts in a page and I want to have a clickable image inserted. After clicking on that image I want to have all the accordions open at once. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Let's say you have Web parts 1-4 that you want to show at once on button click as you said. You should add one content editor web part or script editor web part and put code bellow:

```
/*This is part where you hide some web parts on page load*/
<style type="text/css">

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1 {
display:none;
}

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 {
display:none;
}

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3 {
display:none;
}

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4 {
display:none;
}
</style>

/* This is part where you create function to show those web parts */
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

function ShowAll()
{
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').show(); 
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').show(); 
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').show(); 
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').show(); 
}
</script>

/* This is part where you create button/you can put an image and than call from it the Show All function */
<tr>
<td><input type=button onClick="ShowAll();return false;" value='Show All'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks .. it's correct but not what I have aimed to do .. I want those accordions to be all collided down after clicking on that button at once.